# Check html input before it's updated

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to implement a time picker in Angular, and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to check if the text input is valid. 
In the html I have an input element that binds to keyPress function.

```
<input matInput style="text-align: right;" [(ngModel)]="hour" type="number" min="0" max="23" (keypress)="keyPress($event)">

keyPress(event: any) {
    const pattern = /^(([[0|1]\d)|(2[0-3]))$/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    let tempHour = this.hour;
    if (!tempHour) {
        tempHour = '0';
    }
    let newHour = (+tempHour * 10 + +inputChar).toString();
    if (newHour.length === 1) {
        newHour = '0' + newHour;
    }

    if (!pattern.test(newHour)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the event passed to the keyPress function only contains the current pressed key. This works fine unless the user moves the input cursor. For example: If user presses key "1", and then moves the cursor backwards and enter a "9". My code will treat it as 19 and let it pass, but the actual input is 91. So I guess I need to some how get the cursor position? Or is there a better way to solve this?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the keypress-event happens before ngModel updates your "hour" variable. In your case I'd suggest to react on the change-event which gets fired after ngModel has already done its update.

```
(change)="onChange($event)"
```

And then your method can look like this

```
<input matInput style="text-align: right;" [(ngModel)]="hour" type="number" min="0" max="23" (change)="onChange($event)">

private lastValue: number = 0;

onChange(event: any) {
    const pattern = /^(([[0|1]\d)|(2[0-3]))$/;

    if (!pattern.test(this.hour)) {
        this.hour = this.lastValue;
    } else {
       this.lastValue = this.hour;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with what you suggested is that it does not prevent invalid values from being displayed.

Comment: I updated my post. Just buffer the last value and override the current hour with it in case of a wrong input.

Comment: Thank you for the update. The reason I wanted to use keypress instead of (change) is because the function triggered by keypress will run the validation before the updating the view. (change) however will update the view first and then validate.

Comment: Okay, I see your point. But then I'd recommend to have a look on directives. That's the better way to catch the current input, validate and manipulate it.